# Dockerのコンテナにホスト上のブラウザから接続できない

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Dockerのコンテナのポートにホストのブラウザから接続するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか?
下のDockerfile, docker-compose.ymlで1344番のポートにホストから接続できるようにしているのですが、ホスト側のブラウザで`localhost:1344`にアクセスしても`サーバへの接続を確立できない`となってしまいます

port 1344ではbottle(pythonのwaf)のアプリケーションを動かしています

使っているDockerのversion: `Docker 1.12.0-rc4-beta19`
OS: `OS X 10.11.6`

Dockerfile:

```
from ubuntu:latest
maintainer myname

run mkdir ~/app

copy vim /root/.vim
copy vimrc /root/.vimrc
#update
run apt-get update

run apt-get -y update
run apt-get -y install libssl-dev
run apt-get -yf install curl 
run apt-get -y install clang 
run apt-get -y install lldb 
run apt-get -y install make 
run apt-get -y install libsqlite3-dev
run apt-get -y install man 
run apt-get -y install vim 
run apt-get -y install git 
run apt-get -y install pkg-config 
run apt-get -y install zip 
run apt-get -y install unzip
run apt-get -y install language-pack-ja-base
run apt-get -y install language-pack-ja
run apt-get -y install language-pack-en-base
run apt-get -y install language-pack-en
run apt-get -y install fcitx-mozc
run apt-get -y install libreadline-dev

# setting locale to japanese

run update-locale LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=ja_JP:ja
env LANG ja_JP.UTF-8
env LC_CTYPE ja_JP.UTF-8
env LC_MESSAGES en_US.UTF-8
run im-config -n fcitx

# end of locale settings

#install postgresql

    run apt-get install postgresql
    run apt-get install libpq-dev
    run apt-get install postgresql-plpython3-9.5

# install latest python3 and some python packages (https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/3db904b3f5407840e591daf3aa54670a685b22b3/3.5/Dockerfile)

    ENV GPG_KEY 97FC712E4C024BBEA48A61ED3A5CA953F73C700D

    ENV PYTHON_VERSION 3.5.2

    # if this is called "PIP_VERSION", pip explodes with "ValueError: invalid truth value '<VERSION>'"
    ENV PYTHON_PIP_VERSION 8.1.2

    RUN set -ex \
        && curl -fSL "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION%%[a-z]*}/Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tar.xz" -o python.tar.xz \
        && curl -fSL "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION%%[a-z]*}/Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tar.xz.asc" -o python.tar.xz.asc \
        && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" \
        && gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$GPG_KEY" \
        && gpg --batch --verify python.tar.xz.asc python.tar.xz \
        && rm -r "$GNUPGHOME" python.tar.xz.asc \
        && mkdir -p /usr/src/python \
        && tar -xJC /usr/src/python --strip-components=1 -f python.tar.xz \
        && rm python.tar.xz \
        \
        && cd /usr/src/python \
        && ./configure \
            --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions \
            --enable-shared \
        && make -j$(nproc) \
        && make install \
        && ldconfig \
        && pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip==$PYTHON_PIP_VERSION \
        && [ "$(pip list | awk -F '[ ()]+' '$1 == "pip" { print $2; exit }')" = "$PYTHON_PIP_VERSION" ] \
        && find /usr/local -depth \
            \( \
                \( -type d -a -name test -o -name tests \) \
                -o \
                \( -type f -a -name '*.pyc' -o -name '*.pyo' \) \
            \) -exec rm -rf '{}' + \
        && rm -rf /usr/src/python ~/.cache

    # make some useful symlinks that are expected to exist
    RUN cd /usr/local/bin \
        && ln -s easy_install-3.5 easy_install \
        && ln -s idle3 idle \
        && ln -s pydoc3 pydoc \
        && ln -s python3 python \
    && ln -s python3-config python-config

    #install some packages

    run pip --no-cache-dir install bottle
    run pip --no-cache-dir install feedparser
    run pip --no-cache-dir install psycopg2
    run pip --no-cache-dir install -U pip
    run pip --no-cache-dir install -U setuptools

# end of latest python installation

#prompt and compiler environment variables
env CC clang
env CXX clang++
run echo 'export PS1="\h:\W \u$ "' >> ~/.bashrc

# git config
run git config --global user.name "myname"
run git config --global user.email "my@email.address"
run git config --global color.ui true
run git config --global core.editor vim

expose 1000
expose 2000
expose 3000
expose 4000
expose 5000

expose 1344
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
    datastore:
        image: busybox:latest
        volumes:
            - ./share:/share_to_container

    ### base (ubuntu)
    base:
        build: ./
        ports:
            - "1344:1344"
            - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
            - ./app:/app
        volumes_from:
            - datastore
        links:
            - db
            - webserver


    db:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: "mysqlfile"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=hello
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/mysql
        volumes_from:
            - datastore

    webserver:
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - ./nginx/mysite.template:/etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.template
        volumes_from:
            - datastore
```

Comment: docker の中からだと、 localhost:1344 は接続できますか？

Comment: Dockerfileの中身が`EXPOSE 1344`だけとはどういうことですか？　少なくともこのDockerfileとdocker-compose.ymlだけで`base`が立ち上がる気がしません。

Answer (score 1):

Dockerfileに`CMD`(または、`ENTRYPOINT`)の記述が無いからだと思われます。

Pythonについては熟知していないため、具体的な記述例を示すことはできませんが、bottleを動かすコマンドを書けば良いかと思います。

また多分ですが、記載されている`Dockerfile`でビルドしたコンテナを`docker run`して、`ps`コマンドでプロセスを確認してみると動作してないのではないかと思います。